# 'Have both' -not sure I'm using this correctly

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Is this correct?

> Have both of today’s meetings been cancelled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Both" is the subject here. ["Both"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun#Plural) is also a plural indefinite pronoun. Therefore, the verb, or the auxiliary verb has to be plural, which means, you are correct, as "have" is plural.

> Both(subject: plural) of today's meetings have been cancelled(plural verb)